# apt-get -f failing on dpkg

Tags: apt, dpkg

So this the the log of what I ran:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-202:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp javascript-common libevent-core-2.0-5 libjs-inherits libjs-jquery libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore
  libssl-dev libssl-doc libuv1 libuv1-dev linux-headers-4.4.0-64 linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-66 linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-70 linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-71 linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72 linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-75 linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-77 linux-headers-4.4.0-77-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-79 linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-81 linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic python-pkg-resources
  snap-confine zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/782 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,404 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 392252 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic_4.4.0-89.112_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic (4.4.0-89.112) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic_4.4.0-89.112_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic/include/config/sensors/adcxx.h.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic/include/config/sensors/adcxx.h'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic_4.4.0-89.112_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm not sure why it's giving me a disk full error when it shows me this with `df`:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              497864       0    497864   0% /dev
tmpfs             101432    3108     98324   4% /run
/dev/xvda1       8117828 5248044   2434508  69% /
tmpfs             507152       0    507152   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             507152       0    507152   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             101436       0    101436   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: I suggest `sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic`, followed by `sudo apt autoremove`, then `sudo apt install linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic`

Comment: use `df -i`  to view inodes (blocks, clusters etc), as if they're all used the remaining space available is wasted.

if you've created lots of tiny files (email for each log entry etc, but never look & clean), you may have used all inodes...

Comment: @guiverc ah, the stats are looking different. `/dev/xvda1` is now at 99% any tips on how to clean?

Comment: include the --inode in your `du` commands to find the directory that's chewing them all up & help you remember or find the culprit.  you'll find a directory with tons of little files that needs reduction probably.

Comment: @guiverc seems like most of it is npm related stuff. Would it be safe to just `rm -rf` that stuff? They're just logs right?

Comment: I can't comment about anything safely with regard js|javascript|npm related as I know zip about it.    I can only suggest that I'd backup (rsync|cp) the files before `rm` so at least you can undo the step if it doesn't work.

Comment: @guiverc okay thanks for your help. seems like there's an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996312/should-i-backup-the-npm-and-node-gyp-folder